# Get class methods using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get all the public methods of  class using reflection when class name is passed as a string as shown in the below method. ?

```
 private  MethodInfo[] GetObjectMethods(string selectedObjClass)
 {
   MethodInfo[] methodInfos;
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(sampleAdapater));
   Type _type = assembly.GetType("SampleSolution.Data.MyData." + selectedObjClass);

  ///get all the methods for the classname passed as string

   return methodInfos;

 }
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = Type.GetType(selectedObjcClass) 
                           .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Will this get methods that are not publicly exposed?

Answer (score 13):

```
// get all public static methods of given type(public would suffer in your case, only to show how you could other BindingFlags)
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = _type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

[Type.GetMethods Method (BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[Type.GetMethods Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx)