# i want to get instruction that lie directly in class body and out of any Method body to calculate RFC

Tags: c#

I want to get all constructors in class `Form1` to calculate the RFC, yes I can get `ComboBox` constructor because I can get it from `Form1()` body but I can't get other constructor like `new TextBox();` or `new Button();` because the it out of any method body and lie directly in class body

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComboBox cm = new ComboBox();

    }
    TextBox tttttttttttttttttt = new TextBox();
    Button bbbbbbbb = new Button();

}
```

Comment: They are global variables not constructors methods.  You are trying to get method and you need variables.

Comment: iam need to get  all called method that lie directly in class body  and out of any methodbody . take (int count = ClassA.cac_RFC();) instead of (Button bbbbbbbb = new Button();)

Comment: Use Reflection : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475209/get-class-methods-using-reflection